# SMTP Connection for SSIS 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssis, smtp, outlook-2013, ssis-2008

I am new to SSIS and trying to figure out a way to set up a SMTP connection for an email. I did some online research about this but didn't find a clear explanation on how set up a smtp connection. Can I use outlook 2013 to send an email from SSIS? If yes then how do I create a new smtp connection using outlook 2013

I am trying to send an email from ssis with the ID like donotreply@abc.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i used `System.Net.Mail` assembly to send email notification. 
Add a script task in your SSIS package and include this code provided that your smtp server is working.

```
private void SendMail(
                  string sendTo,
                  string from,
                  string subject,
                  string body,
                  bool isBodyHtml,
                  string SMTPServer,
                  string userName,
                  string password,
                  string domain,
                  string attachments,
                  string sendCC)
        {

            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage oMessage = default(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage);
            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient mySmtpClient = default(System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient);

            oMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(from, sendTo, subject, body);
            oMessage.CC.Add(sendCC);
            oMessage.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;

            mySmtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(SMTPServer, 25);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
            {
                mySmtpClient.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            }
            else
            {
                mySmtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
            }
            mySmtpClient.Send(oMessage);
        }
```